# c# компиляция проекта без visual studio

Tags: c#, msbuild

как компилировать программу wpf без студии? 
пишу в консоли:

`D:\prog\VS2017\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe D:\VS проекты\Журнал\Журнал\Журнал.csproj`
получаю error: можно указать только одни проект

Comment: [гляньте на метаните](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/1.3.php)

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц там только про компиляцию одного файла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заключите пути в кавычки, во втором у вас пробел, скорее всего MsBuild считает его как два аргумента - 
"D:\prog\VS2017\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "D:\VS проекты\Журнал\Журнал\Журнал.csproj"